# Converting JSON Data from NSData to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, ipad

I have a PHP service that returns me the following response in NSData format. After converting the same into NSString using:

```
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I get the following:

```
[
    {
        "Emp_Name": "Krishna Mamidi",
        "Emp_Designation": "Driver",
        "Emp_Type": "Permanent",
        "Joining_Date": "05-MAR-2011",
        "Salary": 10000
    },
    {
        "Emp_Name": "Aditya Reddy",
        "Emp_Designation": "supervisor",
        "Emp_Type": "Permanent",
        "Joining_Date": "06-MAR-2011",
        "Salary": 9000
    },
    {
        "Emp_Name": "Rajiv krishna",
        "Emp_Designation": "director",
        "Emp_Type": "Permanent",
        "Joining_Date": "01-MAR-2011",
        "Salary": 100000
    }
]
```

The above is in correct JSON Format.

Having received the NSData format of the above, I use the following to convert the same into JSON Dictionary:

```
NSError *error = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                 JSONObjectWithData:data
                 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSDictionary *deserializedDictionary = nil;

if (jsonObject != nil && error == nil)
{
    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        //Convert the NSData to NSDictionary in this final step
        deserializedDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
    }
}
```

However the "deserializedDictionary" is always null or empty. Basically it never came inside the If Loop above.

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and am not able to. Please help

Comment: Array of dictionary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json object is an array try with `NSArray` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Cant believe it was such a simple answer. Thank for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because the JSON returned is an array, not a dictionary. Try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([jsonObject class]));
```

Comment: Yes, used an array instead of dictionary and solved the issue. Thanks for the help